# Nginx 403 Forbiden during Prestashop installation

Tags: nginx

I am trying to install Prestashop on my Centos 7 server with Nginx as a webserver.

Here are the steps I took:

```
wget https://download.prestashop.com/download/releases/prestashop_1.7.4.2.zip

unzip prestashop_1.7.4.2.zip  ((gives 3 files, including prestapshop.zip))

unzip prestapshop.zip -d /var/www/example.com/public_html

chmod 755 /var/www/example.com/public_html/ -R

chown nginx:nginx * /var/www/example.com/public_html -R
```

But when I try to access *https://example.com* I get a **403 Forbidden** response.

Here is my */etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf* file content:

```
 server{
   root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

   server_name example.com www.example.com MY_SERVER_IP;

   location / {
      index index.html index.htm;
      #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
      root html;
   }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
 server{
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



   listen 80;

   server_name example.com www.example.com MY_SERVER_IP;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Cheers

**p.s:** I ran all thoses commands as root

**p.s2:** the Certbot parts in my example.com.conf file were added automaticaly by Certbot (software that install SSL certificate)

**Also here are the nginx error logs I get after trying to access to my website:**

```
2018/08/30 05:53:04 [error] 27114#0: *6 directory index of "/var/www/example.com/public_html/install/" is forbidden, client: MY_SERVER_IP, server: lemeilleur$
2018/08/30 05:53:56 [error] 27114#0: *9 directory index of "/var/www/example.com/public_html/install/" is forbidden, client: MY_SERVER_IP, server: lemeilleur$
2018/08/30 06:30:26 [error] 27114#0: *12 directory index of "/var/www/example.com/public_html/install/" is forbidden, client: MY_SERVER_IP, server: lemeilleu$
```

( "lemeilleu" is a part of my website URL but I don't know what does lemeilleu$ correspond to )

Output of **ls -Z /var/www/example.com/public_html/**

```
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                admin
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                app
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                bin
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                cache
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                classes
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                config
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                controllers
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                docs
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                download
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                error500.html
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                images.inc.php
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                img
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                index.php
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                init.php
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                install
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                INSTALL.txt
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                js
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                LICENSES
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                localization
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                mails
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                modules
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                override
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                pdf
-rwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                src
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                themes
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                tools
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                translations
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                upload
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                var
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                vendor
drwxr-xr-x nginx nginx ?                                webservice
```

And lastly, the */etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf* file:

```
user = nginx

group = nginx

listen.owner = nginx

listen.group = nginx

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: please provide error log in nginx. if its permission error in nginx, there is should be some hint in there.

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono Thx for your support, I just edited my post

Comment: Please run `ls -Z /var/www/example.com/public_html/` and add the output.

Comment: hm, usually this should show the selinux contexts. selinux is usually a prime candidate for these problems with centos. Can you run `sestatus` to see if it is enabled? If it is, a re-labeling of the filesystem will be necessary to show the contexts. To do so you have to create the file `/.autorelabel` and reboot.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I ran *sestatus* and it indicated "disabled"

Comment: I suspect the source of the problem being the users permissions, I edited my post again to show you the content of  **/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf**, actully I don't understand the role of the user/group "nginx"

Comment: Hi, why you dont have index.php in your index directive ? you just have index.html and index.htm try add index.php and try add autoindex on; to list installation directory, also try access to your install dir as install/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this issue. Even when running *nginx -t* , if everything is ok, does not mean that it actually is regarding to your nginx.conf content (or *yoursite.com.conf* content).

So, my problem was the most comon one's met with Nginx and 403 Forbiden message, i.e, as you can notice on my .conf file, the line `index index.html index.htm;` was not well placed, it has to be global, so outside and above the *location* layers, like so:

```
 server{
   root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

   server_name example.com www.example.com MY_SERVER_IP;

   index index.php index.html index.htm;

   location / {
      #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
```